# Resequence column numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a column with numbers in a sequence, but for some numbers they can be in groups with several of the same number. Then when the user deletes out a group, there can be a gap in the numbers.

What I want to do is re-sequence that column so it starts at 1, then proceeds up to the last column. So for example, the table column named `Item` could look like this:

```
1
1
2
3
5
5
7
8
8
```

and I want it to convert to this:

```
1
1
2
3
4
4
5
6
6
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: That does not seem like a good design.  For just one deletion you might need to update the entire table.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Remember that DB's don't need to be /that/ human readable, and the program does not really care if it has a 4 or a 5.

Comment: Yes, I would update the table with each deletion. This is a table named Scope, where each scope (some text entered in) can relate to the same Item or a different Item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, amflare. I think I could easily output the information to the user differently than it's stored in the DB, which would then solve my problem.

Comment: But I'm still interested to know if this is possible in MySQL. Someone might know.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't encourage to do this, but you can re-number your values after each update

```
set @cnt = 0;
update test t set t.number=@cnt:=@cnt+1;
```

Update: this will increment the number field by one

Comment: OP has dupes in their data, which this would obliterate. Data loss.

Comment: That's true, I've just noticed the dupes. More complex approach is needed, stored procedure for example